# Cannot see all tabs in ttk.Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tabs, ttk

I have some trouble with the tabs from the ttk Notebook class in python 2.7.
I cannot see all the tabs I create.

I made a minimal code to view the problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()
nb = ttk.Notebook(root, width=320, height=240)
nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
page0 = Frame(nb)
page1 = Frame(nb)
page2 = Frame(nb)
page3 = Frame(nb)
page4 = Frame(nb)
nb.add(page0, text="0")
nb.add(page1, text="1")
nb.add(page2, text="2")
nb.add(page3, text="3")
nb.add(page4, text="4")

root.mainloop()
```

All I can see is

[image: this]

I tried to change the number of tabs and I noticed the size of the top tab bar changes and unless there's only one single lonely tab, I cannot see all of them, as you can see:

[image: that]

What I tried that didn't do anything:

- Setting tabs width
- Moving the .pack() around
- Adding .pack() to the tabs
- Using ttk.Frame instead of tk.Frame
- Googling for a similar problem

What I tried that worked but isn't what I want:

- Not using tabs (too many stuff to show)
- Having only one tab

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug in ttk. If you add a space in front of or behind every label (eg: `text=" 1"` they all show up.

Comment: @BryanOakley  On Windows, it is worse.  I need 6 spaces after `4` to see `4 ` on a tab the same as others.

Comment: I open https://bugs.python.org/issue26682 about this issue, mostly as documentation of the bug.

Comment: I'm doing this on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit. I needed to add 4 spaces before the numbers.

When I tried to do this at home, it worked with a single character (windows 7 pro 64bits).

I haven't looked the exact version of python, but the one I use at work has been installed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did fix your issue however, I have no idea why tk is doing this. I solved this tab over-lapping by increasing the length of the tab text. I changed this portion of your code:

```
nb.add(page0, text="long_name1")
nb.add(page1, text="long_name2")
nb.add(page2, text="long_name3")
nb.add(page3, text="long_name4")
nb.add(page4, text="long_name5")
```

Once again I don't know why tk does this! Someone that is more experienced with tk could probably tell you why.

Comment: By shrinking your long names, the minimum that works is 3 chars, with first and last non-blank.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I had to use 5 chars minimum to be able to see all the tabs.